# Error while connecting Sonar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I am trying to use the eclipse plugin to connect to an instance of sonar that I have installed locally on my machine:
   I am using the following details:

```
http:// localhost:9000
 username:admin
 password:admin
```

but it is showing as error **instance**

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.servers.ServersManager.getServers(ServersManager.java:41)
at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui.internal.preferences.SonarServerPreferencePage.initTable(SonarServerPreferencePage.java:92)
at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui.internal.preferences.SonarServerPreferencePage.createContents(SonarServerPreferencePage.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:232)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1501)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$14.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1252)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:674)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:708)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:704)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:867)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1205)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1230)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:419)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:65)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

I have run analysis of the project before trying to connect.
What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you provided the server address in the Eclipse Sonar plugin preferences or edited the preconfigured entry? Also not every version of Sonar can be used with every version of Eclipse, so [make sure that yours fits](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse). And finally, please verify that you are not using the local analysis mode. Although the Sonar installation is on the same machine, you want to use the server mode analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the problem is with the version of Eclipse that I used (Helios) I have switched to Kepler and everything works fine.